# How do I modify a custom entity delete form?

Tags: entities, forms

I have a custom entity (*Possession*) which has a non-standard edit form. The route for the edit form is the following.

```yaml
entity.possession.edit:
path: '/individual/{individual}/possession/{possession}/edit'
defaults:
  _entity_form: 'possession.edit'
  _title: 'Edit Possession'
requirements:
  _permission: 'access administration pages'
options:
  _admin_route: FALSE 
  parameters:
    individual:
      type: entity:individual
    possession:
      type: entity:possession
```

That seems to work fine. Instead, the delete form doesn't work. When I click on *delete*, I get the following exception.

> Symfony\Component\Routing\ExceptionMissingMandatoryParametersException: Some mandatory  parameters are missing ("individual") to generate a URL for route "entity.possession.edit_form". in Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGenerator->doGenerate() (line 182 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/UrlGenerator.php).

After a little bit of digging, I noticed that the *cancel* link on the delete form redirects users to the edit form, which needs those parameters. I ran into this problem with the List Builder page, but I just fixed it in the code for that page.

I tried to edit the PossessionDeleteForm.php file that was generated from Drupal Console. I added a `buildForm()` method.

```php
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form = parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
  $entity = $this->entity;

  $form['actions']['cancel']['#url'] =  Url::fromRoute('entity.possession.edit_form', [
  'possession' => $entity->id(),
  'individual' => $entity->get('individual_id')->target_id,
  ]);  
  return $form; 
}
```

If I use `ksm()` to inspect the form, it seems it's setup correctly, but it doesn't change the thrown exception. I also tried adding the `getCancelURL()` method to the class with a basic URL, but it didn't fix the error.

```php
public function getCancelURL() {
  return new Url('system.admin_content');
}
```

Next I tried the `urlRouteParamters()` method in the entity class.

```php
protected function urlRouteParameters($rel) {
  $uri_route_parameters = parent::urlRouteParameters($rel);
   
  if ($rel === 'edit_form') {   
    $uri_route_parameters['individual'] = $this->get('individual_id')->target_id;
  }

  return $uri_route_parameters;
}
```

That also didn't work. I have no idea what else to do here.

What is the correct way to redirect users to the edit form, when deleting the entity is cancelled?

Answer (score 0):

The relationship is the key of the url relationships, aka edit-form, not edit_form. Try that in urlRouteParameters() and what you are doing should work.

Comment: That didn't seem to help. It seems like that will work everywhere except on the delete form, which is still throwing a white screen with that same error. It seems like nothing is affecting this.

Comment: might be because of local tasks.. but I'm not sure why you only do that for edit and not for view and delete too in which case it should work..